# dependent variation woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add variation in a product that has three type of Metal (Gold, Sliver, Yellow Gold). Each Metal has different type of Stones, so when someone selects Metal like Gold then stone drop-down values will be changed. How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem when creating a website that sold custom decorated cookies. There were too many options for the standard WooCommerce variation which seems to be only useful for selling a single item where the variant is a single thing like color, size, etc.

I see three options:

1) Create a product for each metal type and then use variants to chose the stone type.

2) Use Gravity Forms plugin + Gravity Form Product Add-ons extension to create product options

3) Use [WooCommerce Product Add-ons](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-add-ons/) plugin.

I used option 3 for my customer because it allowed me to change the price of the items depending on the options chosen and the price updated at the bottom of the product page nicely. If you follow the link above there is information about option 2 on the page as well.

Option 3 doesn't allow for conditional logic, but you could add all the stones as options then hide/show the appropriate ones using a little CSS & JavaScript depending on the type of metal they chose.

Comment: Thanks Justin Good idea i created product for each Metal and Stone and   add custom fields with ACF and some js to redirect :)